# Finding Large Subset of Variables Approximately Equal, Low-Cost with Neural Network

Tags: algorithms, neural-networks

I was reading David J.C. MacKay's [Information Theory, Inference and Learning Algorithms](https://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/itila/book.html)(pdf available in the link), and in section 16.4 of Chapter 16: Message Passing, he writes about how only separable problems can be solved using a message passing approach. One of the non-separable problems he mentions is:

> 2. the size of the largest group of soldiers who share a common height (rounded to the nearest centimetre)

... and he goes on to write:

> One of the challenges of machine learning is to find low-cost solutions to problems like these. The problem of finding a large subset of variables that are approximately equal can be solved with a neural network approach ([Hopfiled and Brody, 2000](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.250483697); [Hopfield and Brody, 2001](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.98.3.1282)).

The two references are about a proposed network that handles memory integration and I am having difficulties drawing any connections between the problem of finding a large subset of variables with approximately equal values and that of memory integration. Are they somehow related? And regardless whether they are related, can said problem really be solved with a neural network approach?